# Query knowledges and datacategory names in a multi language org

Tags: soql, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

The article knowledges are written in two languages: dutch (master) and french. When I run this query:

```
 SELECT Id, Title, language, articleNumber,
  (
    SELECT Id, DataCategoryName
    FROM DataCategorySelections
  )
FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE publishStatus='online'
```

I noticed that only the dutch Knowledge__kav  records have a data category name:
[image]
What's the reason? And how can I query the French knowledges with the data category names?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this behavior in my org wherein English(en_US) is the default language and others as French(fr), Dutch (nl_NL).

I can see that DataCategorySelections records are not returned for articles submitted for translation for fr and nl_NL.

Basically, DataCategorySelections do not return on translations. This is *working as designed* (#W-868100). However, Since the Article Number and record Id is same for Translated and Original article, you can map the translated articles with Data Categories using "Article Number, Id" at the back end.

Alternatively, you can use WITH DATA CATEGORY as mentioned in [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm)

> SELECT Id, Title, language, articleNumber FROM Knowledge__kav where
> publishStatus = 'Online' WITH  DATA CATEGORY Langcategories__c
> ABOVE_OR_BELOW All__c

Here Langcategories__c is the categorygroup and All__c is the parent category